# TKinter: how to create a histogram?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I create a histogram with TKinter and python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will help : http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm or http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/canvas.html

Comment: So, I should build it by myself ? Isn't there a histogram widget ?

Comment: yes u need to if ur using tkinter well there histogram widgets in other libraries : http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/screenshots.html#histograms

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any out-of-the-box histogram widget. You may have to write your own. You may be interested by the [Widget Construction Kit](http://www.effbot.org/zone/wck.htm) to help you in this task.